# Javascript: onclick event not being fired

Tags: javascript, html

I am not very familiar with JavaScript. I am trying to find out a conceptual mistake I am making below. The onclick event is not being fired. I read some blog posts which discuss a similar issue but I didn't find any satisfactory answers. Is it more the way it's invoked?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("itemCost").value;
  var res = str.split(",");
  var sum = 0;

  for (var x = 0; x < res.length; x++) {
    sum += parseInt(res[x]);
  }
  document.getElementById("result").value = sum / res.length;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" id="calculate" value="calculate" onclick="myFunction()" />
</div>
<div>
  <label>Average shipment cost</label>
  <input type="text" name="resultval" id="result" />
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong here? myFunction is invoked properly.

Comment: itemCost is an input ?

Comment: there is no element with an `id` value of `"itemCost"` in your code

Comment: Maybe has to do with your html file structure are you getting on console: `myFunction is not defined` in chrome dev tools?

Comment: The code does work properly, which means `myFunction` gets invoked as click event handler, until one does try to read the `value` property of a null value due to NOT having an element with the expected `id` of "itemCost'" . The error log looks like this ... `{ "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null", "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js", "lineno": 21, "colno": 48 }`. Please update your code example by providing the correct environment, like the missing element, to it.

Answer (score 1):

The provided example code does work as soon as an item cost element is accessible. In case of the latter featuring a comma separated list of just digits the script does even calculate and write a mathematically correct result. Otherwise the result most probably will be `NaN` ...

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("itemCost").value;
  var res = str.split(",");
  var sum = 0;

  for (var x = 0; x < res.length; x++) {
    sum += parseInt(res[x]);
  }
  document.getElementById("result").value = sum / res.length;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>comma separated list of number values
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="itemCostVal" id="itemCost" value="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" id="calculate" value="calculate" onclick="myFunction()" />
</div>
<div>
  <label>Average shipment cost
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="resultval" id="result" />
</div>
```